# How to select bits of a main matrix using a submatrix and store the selected its in an array?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let `A = 6x6 matrix`,
which contains binary bits (`nXn`  matrix).`

```
A=[ 1 0 1 0 1 0 ; 0 1 1 0 1 1;1 1 0 1 1 0; 0 0 1 0 0 1;0 1 1 0 1 1;0 1 0 1 1 1];
```

Let `B` be a `3x3`sub matrix of `A`

```
B = [1 0 1;0 1 1;1 1 0];
```

Now, I want to select the bits `1 0 1 1 0`,  i.e, need to select bits present in positions `(1,1) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2) (3,3)`.

Next I need to traverse this pattern in main Matrix `A`.

So, with the above pattern total bits selected will be `20` and remaining positions bits will be `16`.

I want store the pattern wise selected values in one array and the values of remaining position values in another array.

Pattern wise selected values,

```
`p1=[1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1];`
```

values of remaining position,

```
p2=[1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1];
```

It would be more helpful if the code is generalized for `nXn` main  matrix.
I have attached the pattern and the procedure as an image.

Can some one help me out?
[Procedure] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMcUl.jpg)
[Pattern] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Ac5.jpg)

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of [How to select bits of a matrix in a particular pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64568857/how-to-select-bits-of-a-matrix-in-a-particular-pattern)

Comment: Please do not re-post the same exact question. Instead, improve the original question so that it can be reopened and answered.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If it is fixed, you can provide an answer on how it was fixed. Understand that this is not a bank of solutions, but ... Continuous study and exchange of accurate information. Vague statements make it difficult to reproduce ... And this solution must already be in our database ... Google is also a solution.
This is now believed to be a programming error. Please report the detailed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. It gives the same answers that you have at least. It should work for any size matrix A. It assumes that the pattern is always 3x3, but that could easily be generalised.

```
A = [1 0 1 0 1 0;0 1 1 0 1 1;1 1 0 1 1 0;0 0 1 0 0 1;0 1 1 0 1 1;0 1 0 1 1 1];
pattern = logical([1 1 0;0 1 0;0 1 1]);

% Split A into 3x3 sub matrices
subs = mat2cell(A, [3,3], [3,3])';

s = size(subs);
p1=[];
p2=[];
for i = 1 : s(1)*s(2)
  sub = subs{i};
  p1 = [p1 sub'(pattern')'];
  p2 = [p2 sub'(~pattern')'];
end 

p1
p2
```